# how to debug a WCF service once it's out of dev env

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service that i've been able to communicate with fine while it's hosted locally.

I have it deployed to a web server in IIS now, and I can get the wsdl file without error by navigating to http://site.com:8000/service/servicename.svc?wsdl

in trying to test this, i've created a console app and was able to successfully add a service reference to this.  But when I try to run a Get() method on the service reference, it just hangs with no response.

How can I begin to debug this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any logging set up?

Comment: no.  nothing i've developed in the code, at least.  are there logs other than IIS logs that I can check?

Comment: Yes, turn on WCF tracing. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342.aspx.

Comment: Anything in the logs when you open Event Viewer?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a service that works in dev but not in IIS, it is often due to a problem with the WCF configuration:

- Is the configuration in place (since you can add service reference it probably is)
- Is the protocol you are using available. The configuration you are using must match what is turned on. For example are you using nettcpip binding without WAS.